# NuGet packages version resolution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Can I use two different versions of a NuGet package (let's take [ProtoBuf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net.Core) for example), in my class library project and in my Visual Studio main project that references it?

I mean, what happens when the assemblies are both copied to the `Bin\Release` output folder?

On the other hand, I guess that under some circumstances, developers might feel uncomfortable upgrading NuGet components because of other projects' dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

While I don't recommend that you use multiple different versions, if you must use the contents of two or more different package versions separately, there is a way to do so.

At this time, you need to bypass the nuget package management and use the assembly directly. This method is the reflection technology in C#, which will not interfere with the code based on other versions of the package.

For example, I have a class library like this:

```
namespace Demo_lib
{
    public class Class1
    { 
        public static string other_version_method()
        {
            return "This is other version method.";
        }
    }

}
```

You can copy the dll of this class library (or the dll in the package) to the project root directory, and set the file copy property to "Copy If Newer" (this is so that the dll can be compiled into a subfile in the compilation directory after compilation folder):

[image]

Then you can do this:

```
    // Load dll file
    var dllPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "other_version/Demo_lib.dll");
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);

    // get the type in dll file
    Type type = assembly.GetType("Demo_lib.Class1");

    // create the object in dll file
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Call the method in dll file
    //int result = (int)type.InvokeMember("MyDLLMethod", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, new object[] { 10, 20 });
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("other_version_method");

    var str3 = method.Invoke(obj, null);

    // output result
    Console.WriteLine(str3);
```

Official document:

[Reflection and Attributes of C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/)

Of course, if you use something that doesn't involve the difference between the two versions, you don't need to do this, and it's okay to directly base on the new version.

## Original Answer:

> I mean, what happens when the assemblies are both copied to the
> Bin\Release output folder?

The answer is that the .dll files of these two versions will not be "both" copied, only the dll file of "newer" package version under the SemVer standard will be built to the bin directory. This is the default behavior.

This means that:

1, If the project you're referencing doesn't involve the changes of the packages, everything will work fine.

2, But if a feature in the referenced project is based on the old version of the package, and you use this feature of the referenced project in current project, then there will be problems, because the old version of .dll will not been built to the build root directory.

Comment: It's hard to think that there are no workarounds to this scenario...

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, we aren't allowed to load assemblies at runtime.

Comment: @abenci Hi abenci, if so, then the answer to your original question is **NO**, actually it will use the newest version of package. Assemblies will not both copy to the bin folder, only the newest version of assembly will be copied to that place. If my answer answered your original question, could we end this question? :)

Comment: I'm waiting for some other point of view...

Comment: @abenci Thanks for your reply! I also hope there has other point of view/a solution in this situation, if there this, please also let me know that. Good Luck! :)